# Find the geometric series of $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I get the series of $$\frac{1}{x}$$ 
What are the procedures for getting this?

Comment: Do you know what the geometric series is and what function it represents as a taylor series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum of an Infinite Geometric series can be represented as $$s=\frac{a}{1-r}$$
Where $a$ is first term of series and $r$ is common ratio, Now coming to your question 
$$s=\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{1-(1-x)}$$
Now assuming that $|1-x|\lt1$
Your series will be 
$$s=1+(1-x)+(1-x)^2+\cdots+(1-x)^n+\cdots$$
You can also verify if the answer is correct
using formula of sum of infinite series above mentioned we get $$s=\frac{a}{1-r}=\frac{1}{1-(1-x)}=\frac{1}{x}$$
And the series can also be written in form of  following summation as
$$s=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-x)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

The geometric series is a power series for the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$. In sum notation we can write $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$. So, if we wanted to find the taylor series of $\frac{1}{x}$ we would only need to find some way of representing the new function via the old one. This can be done by changing $x$ to $(1-x)$ in the sum. So our new series is $\frac{1}{1-(1-x)}=\frac{1}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x)^n$.

Comment: Sorry, I need the geometric series

Comment: @Eoin there is a typo: the terms in the sum should be $x^n$ and $(1-x)^n$ rather than $nx^n$ and $n(1-x)^n$.

Comment: @intialsbd you're right. My mistake